# Ctrl+alt+end not working inside remote desktop

Tags: keyboard

I am using dell laptop
I wanna change password but ctrl+alt+end is not working

Is there is any other way to change the password?

Answer (score 0):

You could setup a script using [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/). Like an alternative key shortcut that would kick off the keys you need.

To change password, I think you could use `control center`.

Disclaimer: Its been over a year since I used windows, so things could have changed.

Source: https://superuser.com/questions/92801/how-to-send-ctrlaltend-to-remote-desktop

Answer (score -1):

Use terminal to change password, if your GUI doesn't works.

Search on Google how to do that change in your OS.

Comment: If I knew him operating system I could give a more exact suggestion.